# Why doesn't Wordpress make thumbnails for videos?

Tags: images, thumbnails, videos, media-modal

I noticed videos in the media gallery always show as an icon preview (unlike files in a file manager, which show a thumbnail.)

Considering that WP integrates Imagemagick, which apparently can extract [frames from video](https://superuser.com/questions/599348/can-imagemagick-make-thumbnails-from-video), why does it not do so for Thumbnails like it does for images?

Comment: Core doesn't integrate Imagemagick, it integrates *support* for Imagemagick if it exists, which may not be the case on some systems. I'll guess that since the implementation has been abstracted away, it only enables things that are possible regardless of implementation.

Comment: @Milo Yes, I know that's how the Image-editor classes work but if the server has Imagemagick why not create thumbnails for video clips?

Comment: consistency? who knows? try asking the people who wrote it.